# application not working in API 21

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an application which has a gridview with images in it. The problem is its showing in all phones except for API 21 i.e. Lollipop version. In Lollipop its shows just background and no gridview. The targetSDK is 21 and minSDK is 8. Any help in this would be much appreciated.

```html
MainActivity

public class MainView extends Activity {
 
 ImageView back, home, site, header;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
     getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER);
     
        setContentView(R.layout.mainview);
        
        
        GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
        
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
            
              Intent myIntent = null;
                 if(position == 0){
                     myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), TheShow.class);
                 }
                 if(position == 1){
                     myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Exhibitor.class);
                 }
                 if(position ==2){
                     myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Visitor.class);
                 }  
                 if(position ==3){
                     myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Conference.class);
                 }  
                 if(position ==4){
                     myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ContactUs.class);
                 }
                 if(position == 5){
                  myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ExhibitorReg.class);
                 }
                 if(position == 6){
                  myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), VisitorReg.class);
                 }
                 
                 if(position == 7){
                  myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), FlrPlan.class);
                 } 
                
                 if(myIntent!=null){
                    startActivity(myIntent); 
                 }
             
             
            }
        });
        
        back=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
  home=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
  site=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
  
  back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MainView.this.onBackPressed();
   }
  });
  
  home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Same Page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  });
  
  site.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
      String url = "http://india-aviation.in/";
          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
          startActivity(i);
   }
  });
  
  header=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  header.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainView.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("About Us");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonOK);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
      dialog.dismiss();
     }
    });

    dialog.show();

    
   } 
  

  });
  
        
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyAdapter(Context context)
        {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            items.add(new Item("The Show", R.drawable.globecopy1));
            items.add(new Item("Exhibitor", R.drawable.workcopy1));
            items.add(new Item("Visitor", R.drawable.visitor1copy1));
            items.add(new Item("Conference", R.drawable.conferencecopy1));
            items.add(new Item("Contact Us", R.drawable.contactus1copy1));
            items.add(new Item("Exhibitor Registration", R.drawable.exregistercopy1));
            items.add(new Item("Visitor Registration", R.drawable.anothercopy1));
            items.add(new Item("Layout Plan", R.drawable.registercopy1));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i)
        {
            return items.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i)
        {
            return items.get(i).drawableId;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
        {
            View v = view;
            ImageView picture;
            TextView name;

            if(v == null)
            {
               v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, viewGroup, false);
               v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
               v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
            }

            picture = (ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.picture);
            name = (TextView)v.getTag(R.id.text);

            Item item = (Item)getItem(i);

            picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
            name.setText(item.name);

            return v;
        }

        private class Item
        {
            final String name;
            final int drawableId;

            Item(String name, int drawableId)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.drawableId = drawableId;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image: libraries added][image: this is the result]

[image: this should be the actual result]

Answer (score 0):

If you app has a values-21 folder in res folder, either set the layout there or delete the folder if you want persistent layout for all APIs.

Comment: I don't have a values-21 folder in Res folder. Do I have to add it?

Comment: No. It is only needed if you want a custom layout for API level 21

Comment: One suggestion. You apps bottom navbar if to small.

Comment: I want same layout for all levels. I've values-v11 and v14 only. But still its showing blank in API21. Any particular reason?

Comment: Does each values folder have a different layout?

Comment: Its just an image and can be adjusted but the main prob is the gridview is not showing. The 3rd pic is from a JelyBean phone and it shows fine navbar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80356/discussion-between-somnath-pal-and-sayan98).